# Most powerful Powershell profile cheat?

Tags: powershell, settings, profile

I am curious what other Powershell developers find useful to store in their Powershell profile. The possibilities are endless.

For example, my most powerful Powershell profile function I routinely use is my *findTextInWorkspace* function. Other developers at my job have now started using it because it proves to be very handy. The function allows me to search all of my local Powershell scripts for a specific text pattern, like a GREP. When a script fails on our build server, I can plug in keywords to track down the culprit. Since we have many duplicate scripts and nested folder structure in our application domain, this function allows me to quickly find the full path to any problematic or misbehaving scripts.

```
# find explicit text in all Workspace powershell scripts
function findTextInWorkspace ([string] $text, [string] $path = "C:\Workspace\*")
{
    dir $path -recurse -filter '*.ps*1' | Get-ChildItem | select-string -pattern $text | Select-Object Path -Unique
}
```

Then I can invoke it, like so:

```
cd C:\Workspace\MyApplication
findTextInWorkspace "thisvariablecausedmybuildtocrash" .
```

**My question is for the Powershell gurus...what is the most powerful "cheat" or enhancment you have seen or used in a Powershell profile?** I am looking for creative and useful answers.

Comment: Please dont close this question. If this gets closed, why is this question left open? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936/good-cheat-sheets

Comment: The question you reference is 4 1/2 years old. ["Avoid questions where every answer is equally valid"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: So age matters? That's ridiculous.

Comment: Policies get refined over time, but old questions/answers with a lot of activity are "grandfathered" in. Such things are always open for discussion on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: The presence of bank robbers in the world doesn't mean robbing banks is ok.

Comment: But it means banks will still be robbed. Ignoring robbers does not mean  that theft is non-existant. Four people upvoted this question in a short amount of time. I would think that would indicate usefulness. Four and a half years ago StackOverflow was a much better and friendlier place.

Comment: At the time of that question, SO was still in private beta and what the site was really going to be was still being hashed out. If it makes you feel better, I voted to close that one too.

Comment: There is no surprise here that you voted to close down perfectly legitimate questions.